# Counting swaps and comparisons in Quicksort (Python)

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort

I'm trying to count the swapping and comparison operations in a quicksort.
I think I set the counters at the right locations, but due to the recursion, I never get the right amount for these values. To 'store' the values throughout the recursion I hand them over as parameters(qui_swap and qui_comp.

For example: When I let this algorithm sort a list with 500 integers, it returns 120 swaps and 1 comparison.

Below is my code:

```py
qui = quicksort(numbers, 0, len(numbers)-1, 0, 0)

def partition(numbers, start_index, end_index, qui_swap):

    # Select the middle value as the pivot.
    midpoint = start_index + (end_index - start_index) // 2
    pivot = numbers[midpoint]
   
    # "low" and "high" start at the ends of the list segment
    # and move towards each other.
    low = start_index
    high = end_index
   
    done = False
    while not done:
        # Increment low while numbers[low] < pivot
        while numbers[low] < pivot:
            low = low + 1
          
      
        # Decrement high while pivot < numbers[high]
        while pivot < numbers[high]:
            high = high - 1
            
      
        # If low and high have crossed each other, the loop
        # is done. If not, the elements are swapped, low is
        # incremented and high is decremented.
        if low >= high:
            done = True
        else:
            temp = numbers[low]
            numbers[low] = numbers[high]
            numbers[high] = temp
            low += 1
            high -= 1
            qui_swap += 1

   
    # "high" is the last index in the left segment.
    return (high, qui_swap)

def quicksort(numbers, start_index, end_index, qui_swap, qui_comp):
    # Only attempt to sort the list segment if there are
    # at least 2 elements

    
    if end_index <= start_index:  
       
        return   
    # Partition the list segment
    
     #count comparisons here
    qui_comp += 1
         
    high = partition(numbers, start_index, end_index,qui_swap)
    qui_swap = high[1]
    
    # Recursively sort the left segment
    quicksort(numbers, start_index, int(high[0]), qui_swap, qui_comp+1)
    
    # Recursively sort the right segment
    quicksort(numbers, int(high[0]) + 1, end_index, qui_swap, qui_comp+1)
    
    return(qui_swap, qui_comp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your quicksort **returns** the updated values of your counters. But you don't assign them.

The last 5 lines of your quicksort function should be :

```
    # Recursively sort the left segment
    l_swap, l_comp = quicksort(numbers, start_index, int(high[0]), qui_swap, qui_comp+1)
    
    # Recursively sort the right segment
    r_swap, r_comp = quicksort(numbers, int(high[0]) + 1, end_index, qui_swap, qui_comp+1)

    qui_swap = l_swap + r_swap
    qui_comp = l_comp + r_comp
    
    return(qui_swap, qui_comp)
```

(and you will also need to change the bare return to this:

```
   if end_index <= start_index:  
        return(qui_swap, qui_comp)
```

Comment: Note that with this modification, the count is probably not correct: sorting the simple list [1,2,3] counts 10 comparisons. It seems a little too much!

Answer (score 0):

Given [Hoare's quicksort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) -

```py
def quicksort(A, lo, hi):
  if lo >= 0 and hi >= 0 and lo < hi:
    p = partition(A, lo, hi)
    quicksort(A, lo, p)
    quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)

def partition(A, lo, hi):
  pivot = A[(hi + lo) // 2]
  i = lo
  j = hi
  while True:
    while A[i] < pivot:
      i += 1
    while A[j] > pivot:
      j -= 1
    if i >= j:
      return j
    A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
```

I would first start with the `partition` function and include `comp` and `swap` counters -

```py
def partition(A, lo, hi):
  comp = 0                     # comparison counter
  swap = 0                     # swap counter
  pivot = A[(hi + lo) // 2]
  i = lo
  j = hi
  while True:
    while A[i] < pivot:
      comp += 1                # increase comparison count
      i += 1
    while A[j] > pivot:
      comp += 1                # increase comparison count
      j -= 1
    if i >= j:
      return (comp, swap, j)   # return comp, swap, and j
    swap += 1                  # increase swap count
    A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
```

`partition` now returns a 3-tuple of `(comp, swap, j)` so we need to adjust `quicksort` accordingly -

```py
def quicksort(A, lo, hi):
  if lo >= 0 and hi >= 0 and lo < hi:
    (comp, swap, p) = partition(A, lo, hi)  # receive 3-tuple
    quicksort(A, lo, p)
    quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)
```

In order for the caller to receive these infos, we have to format `quicksort`'s return value. We can start by returning `(comp, swap)` -

```py
def quicksort(A, lo, hi):
  if lo >= 0 and hi >= 0 and lo < hi:
    (comp, swap, p) = partition(A, lo, hi)
    quicksort(A, lo, p)
    quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)
    return (comp, swap)           # return comp, swap
```

But that only includes the comparison and swap counters for the first pass.  Now that we know `quicksort` returns a 2-tuple `(comp, swap)` we can get those from the recursive calls too -

```py
def quicksort(A, lo, hi):
  if lo >= 0 and hi >= 0 and lo < hi:
    (comp, swap, p) = partition(A, lo, hi)
    (lcomp, lswap) = quicksort(A, lo, p)                # left comp, swap
    (rcomp, rswap) = quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)            # right comp, swap
    return (comp + lcomp + rcomp, swap + lswap + rswap) # sum comp, swap
```

Currently `quicksort` only has a return value under the `if` branch, outside of that it implicitly returns `None`. We need to provide the empty `comp` and `swap` counters in this case -

```py
def quicksort(A, lo, hi):
  if lo >= 0 and hi >= 0 and lo < hi:
    (comp, swap, p) = partition(A, lo, hi)
    (lcomp, lswap) = quicksort(A, lo, p)
    (rcomp, rswap) = quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)
    return (comp + lcomp + rcomp, swap + lswap + rswap)
  return (0,0)  # base case, return empty counters
```

And we're done! Our new `quicksort` returns a value, so make sure to store it to a variable or `print` it -

```py
x = [5,0,9,7,4,2,8,3,1,6]
print(quicksort(x, 0, len(x)-1))
print(x)
```

Result -

```py
(31, 9)                          # 31 comparisons, 9 swaps
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]   # sorted result
```

Now `x` is sorted. If we repeat the `quicksort`, we get different comparison and swap counters -

```py
print(quicksort(x, 0, len(x)-1))
print(x)
```

```py
(25, 0)                          # 25 comparisons, 0 swaps
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]   # sorted result
```

And for small arrays, we can verify the result more easily -

```py
y = [2,1,3]
print(quicksort(y, 0, len(y)-1))
print(y)
```

```py
(3, 1)                           # 3 comparisons, 1 swap 
[1, 2, 3]                        # sorted result
```

---

If you're having trouble putting the line-by-line edits in your program, here's a complete working version -

```py
def quicksort(A, lo, hi):
  if lo >= 0 and hi >= 0 and lo < hi:
    (comp, swap, p) = partition(A, lo, hi)
    (lcomp, lswap) = quicksort(A, lo, p)
    (rcomp, rswap) = quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)
    return (comp + lcomp + rcomp, swap + lswap + rswap)
  return (0,0)

def partition(A, lo, hi):
  comp = 0
  swap = 0
  pivot = A[(hi + lo) // 2]
  i = lo
  j = hi
  while True:
    while A[i] < pivot:
      comp += 1
      i += 1
    while A[j] > pivot:
      comp += 1
      j -= 1
    if i >= j:
      return (comp, swap, j)
    swap += 1
    A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
```

```py
x = [5,0,9,7,4,2,8,3,1,6]
print(quicksort(x, 0, len(x)-1))
print(x)

print(quicksort(x, 0, len(x)-1))
print(x)
```

```
(31, 9)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
(25, 0)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

```py
y = [2,1,3]
print(quicksort(y, 0, len(y)-1))
print(y)
```

```
(3, 1)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I've copied your code and tried it. When I use a list with more than 5 elements, it seems like it's not working?

Comment: the code demo shows it working on a 10 element list. where is you’re going wrong?

Comment: It seems like it never terminates (or at least runs for a very long time). There are no errors given.

Comment: Hi again @PilotF4, I had one small typo in the name of the function that I was using for testing that made its way into the post. Be careful to follow the examples closely and you should get the exact same output here. I made an update that includes the full program so you don't have to piece it together yourself. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Sorry for the very late response, this worked!
Thank you so much!