# Recursive Quicksort using Lambdas

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, quicksort

I'm trying to implement a recursive quicksort algorithm using two methods (swap, partition) while running the main algorithm using recursion in a lambda expression. I'm getting an infinite recursion error and honestly I can't find the syntax error. Can someone help me out? Thanks :)

```
def swap(array, a, b):
        array[a], array[b] = array[b], array[a]
def partition(array, high, low):
    pivot = array[high]
    i = low
    for x in range(low, high-1):
        if array[x] < pivot:
            i+=1
            swap(array, array[x], array[high])
    return i
g = lambda array, low, high: g(array,low,partition(array,high,low)-1)+g(array,partition(array,high,low)+1,high) if low < high else print("not sorted")
```

Comment: When you have infinite recursion, don't look for a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in `partition`:

- The call to `swap` is passing *values* from your list, instead of *indices*.
- Even when the previous mistake is corrected, it will either move the pivot value to the `low+1` index, or it will not move at all.
- The returned index `i`, should be the one where the pivot was moved. In a correct implementation that means `i` is the last index to which a value was moved, which was the value at index `high`. This is not what is happening, as already with the *first* swap the pivot value is moved.
- The swap should be of the *current* value with the value at `i`, so that all values up to the one at index `i` are less or equal to the pivot value.

Here is the corrected `partition` function:

```
def partition(array, high, low):
    pivot = array[high]
    i = low - 1
    for x in range(low, high+1):
        if array[x] <= pivot:
            i+=1
            swap(array, x, i)
    return i
```

These are the issues in the function `g`:

- It is supposed to perform the sort in-place, so the `+` operator for lists should not occur here, as that would create a new list. Moreover, the base case (in `else`) does not return anything, so the `+` operator will fail with an error
- `partition(array,high,low)` is called twice, which is not only a waste, but the second call will in most cases return a different result, because the pivot can be different. This means the second call of `g` will potentially not work with an *adjacent* partition, but will either leave an (unsorted) gap, or work on an overlapping partition.

Here is a correction for the function `g`:

```
def g(array, low, high):
    if low < high:
        i = partition(array, high, low)
        g(array, low, i-1)
        g(array, i+1, high)
```

You should also consider using a better name than `g`, and change the order of the `high`/`low` parameters for `partition`: that reversed order is a good way to confuse the readers of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Hoare's quicksort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) implemented in Python -

```py
def quicksort(A, lo, hi):
  if lo >= 0 and hi >= 0 and lo < hi:
    p = partition(A, lo, hi)
    quicksort(A, lo, p)
    quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)

def partition(A, lo, hi):
  pivot = A[(hi + lo) // 2]
  i = lo
  j = hi
  while True:
    while A[i] < pivot:
      i += 1
    while A[j] > pivot:
      j -= 1
    if i >= j:
      return j
    swap(A, i, j)

def swap(A, i, j):
  A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
```

You can write `g` using `lambda` if you wish, but I would recommend to `def`ine an ordinary function instead -

```py
g = lambda a: quicksort(a, 0, len(a) - 1)
```

Given a sample input, `x` -

```py
x = [5,0,9,7,4,2,8,3,1,6]
g(x)
print(x)
```

```py
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

See [this related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70624906/633183) if you would like to count the number of comparisons and swaps used.